# More elegant way of comparing large numbers divided by a common modulus

Tags: c#, datetime, modulus

I have this comparison of time ticks, but I only want to know that the ticks are equal up to a certain granularity. For that I've come up with an idea of dividing ticks by a common modulus, subtracting the remainder and compare what's left.

```
long value1 = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
long value2 = 8884736516532874;

Assert.IsTrue((value1 - value1 % 1000)==(value2 - value2 % 1000));
```

I am sure there's gotta be a more elegant, better way of doing that.

Comment: why not just subtract both values and check if their difference is smaller than a given epsilon? Btw.: the ssame things you would do for comparing double for example.

Comment: If you're trying to compare date times and ignore one of the components (e.g. ignore year but compare month and day), modulus is not going to work, because date/time values are not periodic (months and years have different numbers of days, for example). What exactly are you trying to do? Can you provide a couple examples of input and output?

Comment: @HimBromBeere, that's something I thought of, but my given epsilon is unknown.

Comment: @John Wu, I know that both values will be within same date, same hours and within 10 minute lag between each other. And this is what I care for. That the only assertion I am trying to get.

Comment: In that case I see no reason to use a modulus at all. Just compute the raw difference.

Comment: How does your modulis by 1000 differ from a pre-defined epsilon? In fact both are some static threasholds for inaccuracies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing with inaccuracies is a pretty common thing, in particular when dealing with floating-point numbers such as `float`.

In your case you can achieve the same by calculating the difference of both values and checking if it is smaller than a pre-defined epsilon:

```
var epsilon = 1000;
Assert.IsTrue(Math.Abs(value1 - value2) < epsilon);
```

As per your comment

> I know that both values will be within same date, same hours and within 10 minute lag between each other

So you can go even a bit further and compare dates directly:

```
var difference = date1.Subtract(date2);
Assert.IsTrue(Math.Abs(difference.TotalMinutes) < 10);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that condition is equals to 
value1 /(10^11) == value2/(10^11)